# Como adicionar contador para cada if do meu código simples

Tags: c, revisão-de-código, contador

```
            #include <stdio.h>
            #include <stdlib.h>
            int main()
            {
                float x,y;
                char k;
                do{
                printf("Este Programa indica o quadrante no plano cartesiano\n");
                printf("Entre com o valor de x:");
                scanf("%f",&x);
                printf("Entre com o valor de y:");
                scanf("%f",&y);
                if((x>0)&&(y>0))
                printf("O Ponto P(%.2f,%.2f) pertence ao primeiro Quadrante\n",x,y);
                else
                {
                  if((x<0)&&(y>0))
                  printf("O Ponto P(%.2f.%.2f) pertence ao segundo Quadrante\n",x,y);
                  else
                  {
                    if((x<0)&&(y<0))
                    printf("O Ponto P(%.2f,%.2f) pertence ao terceiro Quadrante\n",x,y);
                    else
                    {
                      if((x>0)&&(y<0))
                      printf("O Ponto P(%.2f,%.2f) pertence ao quarto Quadrante\n",x,y);
                      else
                      {
                        if((x==0)&&((y>0||y<0)))
                        printf("O Ponto P(%.2f,%.2f) esta no eixo y\n",x,y);
                        else
                        {
                          if((y==0)&&((x>0||x<0)))
                          printf("O Ponto P(%.2f,%.2f) esta no eixo x\n",x,y);
                          else
                          {
                            if((x==0)&&(y==0))
                            printf("O Ponto P(%.2f,%.2f) esta na origem\n\n",x,y);

                fflush(stdin);
                printf("\nDeseja digitar outro ponto. (S)/(N):\n");
                scanf("%c",&k);
                }while((k=='S')||(k=='s'));
            system("Pause");
```

Gostaria de implementar neste código um contador e depois escrever os totais de pontos em cada uma das situações. Por exemplo, "Total de pontos no eixo x: ". Porém, não estou conseguindo por algum motivo. Se alguém puder dar uma dica, agradeço.

Comment: `float` vs `double`: prefere **sempre** `double` quando tiveres de trabalhar com números de vírgula flutuante. (As excepções a esta regra são muito muito poucas.)

Comment: Como usas `system("Pause")` depreendo que estejas a usar o Windows. Em todos os outros Sistemas Operativos actuais a função `fflush(stdin)` tem Comportamento Indefinido. Se conseguires escrever o teu código usando outra forma de conseguir essas funcionalidades (`system("Pause")` e `fflush(stdin)`), tornas esse mesmo código mais portável.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não explicou exatamente por que não está conseguindo, então vou falar um pouco dos problemas que encontrei e apresentar uma solução simples.

A primeira coisa é a indentação. Quando você tiver um monte de `if`/`else`s desse jeito, coloque da seguinte forma:

```
if (condicao1) {
    // código
} else if (condicao2) {
    // código
} else if (condicao3) {
   // código
}
```

Assim você evita de aninhar à toa blocos que não estão logicamente um dentro do outro e ainda facilita a ler.

Com a indentação ajeitada e alguns ajustes que comento em seguida, ficou assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char k;

    int qtdDePontosNoEixoX = 0;
    int qtdDePontosNoEixoY = 0;

    do {
        printf("Este Programa indica o quadrante no plano cartesiano\n");
        printf("Entre com o valor de x:");
        float x;
        scanf("%f",&x);
        printf("Entre com o valor de y:");
        float y;
        scanf("%f",&y);

        if((x>0)&&(y>0)) {
            printf("O Ponto P(%.2f,%.2f) pertence ao primeiro Quadrante\n",x,y);
        } else if((x<0)&&(y>0)) {                    
            printf("O Ponto P(%.2f.%.2f) pertence ao segundo Quadrante\n",x,y);
        } else if((x<0)&&(y<0)) {
            printf("O Ponto P(%.2f,%.2f) pertence ao terceiro Quadrante\n",x,y);
        } else if((x>0)&&(y<0)) {
            printf("O Ponto P(%.2f,%.2f) pertence ao quarto Quadrante\n",x,y);
        } else if((x==0)&&((y>0||y<0))) {
            printf("O Ponto P(%.2f,%.2f) esta no eixo y\n",x,y);
            qtdDePontosNoEixoY++;
        } else if((y==0)&&((x>0||x<0))) {
            printf("O Ponto P(%.2f,%.2f) esta no eixo x\n",x,y);
            qtdDePontosNoEixoX++;
        } else if((x==0)&&(y==0)) {
            qtdDePontosNoEixoX++;
            qtdDePontosNoEixoY++;
            printf("O Ponto P(%.2f,%.2f) esta na origem\n\n",x,y);
        }

        printf("\nDeseja digitar outro ponto. (S)/(N):\n");
        getchar(); // lendo e jogando fora a quebra de linha que fica na entrada por causa do Enter
        k = getchar();
    } while(k=='S' || k=='s');

    printf("%d dos pontos que você digitou estavam no eixo X e %d estavam no eixo Y\n", 
              qtdDePontosNoEixoX, qtdDePontosNoEixoY);

}
```

Retirei o `#include <stdlib.h>`, que não está sendo usado. É interessante saber o que você inclui e por quê, pra não acrescenter coisa ao seu executável à tôa.

Movi a declaração das variáveis `x` e `y` para perto dos respectivos `scanf`. Tente declarar suas variáveis sempre perto de onde você está usando. Assim você evita de poluir um espaço de nomes maior do que precisa e de ter que ficar subindo e descendo no código pra descobrir o tipo das variáveis ou seu valor inicial.

Retirei o `fflush(stdin)`. A função `fflush` só serve para fluxos de **saída**. Para fluxos de entrada ela tem o **comportamento indefinido**. Coloquei um simples `getchar()` para ler esse Enter e jogar fora e isso basta para esse caso simples (se formos começar a fazer verificações de erro a nível de produção, teria que mexer em muito mais coisa).

Quanto à solução, depois de organizar o código, fica bem fácil ver onde tem que mexer: só criar duas variáveis, uma para cada eixo, inicializar com 0 e incrementar em 1 nos casos adequados.